# How to display username instead of id in a list in octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

In my case I have a backend list and I got the updated UserId on the list. But I have no Idea how to display the Username instead of the UserId. Is there anyone can help me to get out of this?
[See the list here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNcyY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to use the *relation* field type, change your `columns.yaml` and instead of use `user_id` something like this:

```
user:
 label: Username
 type: relation
 select: login
```

And remember `user` is the name of your relationship defined in the `belongsTo` array

You should have defined the relationship right in your model

```
<?php

class YourModel extends Model
{
  $belongsTo = ['user'=>'Backend\Models\User'];
}
```

For further information http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-relation

Comment: Thank you OsDev for the answer. It works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

in your YourModel.php ,add this relation

```
public $hasOne = [
        'user' => ['Backend\Models\User', 'key' => 'id', 'otherKey' => 'user_id']
            ];
```

in your columns.yaml,add this

```html
 user:
        label: 'Username'
        type: text
        select: username //field from users table
        relation: user //relation name is the key defined in model "hasone" relation
```